# Mapping Rainforest Deforestation in Peru

Tags: data, forest-ecology, peru

I'm working on a project on the the rainforest deforestation in Peru. This is related to the work of http://www.coolearth.org/our-mission but I am not affiliated with the organization.

I'm hoping to produce several thematic maps visualizing the chronology and rate of logging, the displacement of villages/people and CO2 released into the atmosphere (and any other data I find that might be relevant--suggestions welcome here too!). Does anyone know where I could find this data?

Also does anyone have any advice on how to best map/represent these variables? I will be using QGIS, so any suggestions for plugins or tools would be welcome!

Comment: Some Shapefile here http://www.natureserve.org/aboutUs/latinamerica/gis_data_downloads.jsp#shapefiles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be interested in this high resolution (30m) dataset from a recent publication:

**High-resolution global maps of 21st-century forest cover change

MC Hansen et al. 2013. Science 342(6160):850-853**
DOI:10.1126/science.1244693

online: http://www.sciencemag.org/content/342/6160/850.short
(full article is paywalled, but you might search for a pdf)

Partial abstract:

> Quantification of global forest change has been lacking despite the recognized importance of forest ecosystem services. In this study, Earth observation  satellite data were used to map global forest loss (2.3 million square kilometers) and gain (0.8 million square kilometers) from 2000 to 2012 at a spatial resolution of 30 meters.

The results have been mapped online here:
http://www.earthenginepartners.appspot.com/science-2013-global-forest

And, according to [this form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1a3iiL1ltWpxStZMSZ7oulOP8HOEWGJYQNg_GFRFgl3g/viewform):

> Our goal is to make the Global Forest Change data available for public download in January 2014.

May be worth checking if this dataset is now available for use in your project, or perhaps you could use screen shots of the existing mapped results

Comment: Hansen data now available for download: http://earthenginepartners.appspot.com/science-2013-global-forest/download.html

Answer (score 4):

There are a several ways to go about this sort of analysis.  I suspect you are not too interested in downloading, processing and analyzing raw Landsat or MODIS data, therefore, I recommend using an existing product from the University of Maryland which derives Vegetation Cover Conversion (VCC) from MODIS data.  From the [UMD Global Land Cover Facility](http://glcf.umd.edu/data/vcc/):

> The Vegetative Cover Conversion (VCC) is an annual data product that
>   reports on changes in land cover at 250m meter spatial resolution. VCC
>   is derived from all seven bands of 16-day composited imagery captured
>   by the MODerate Resolution Imaging Spectroradiometer (MODIS). Please
>   note that this is an alarm product and that due to coarse resolution
>   there are bound to be errors of omission. The provisional edition
>   currently available online depicts global change due to vegetation
>   burning and change within the tropics due to anthropogenic
>   deforestation.

---

I looked up a tile from an area in Rhondonia that I know to have high deforestation rates and downloaded it from this [FTP site](ftp://ftp.glcf.umd.edu/modis/VCC/Deforestation/).  I did some minor manipulation in a GIS--namely, Calculating Statistics so that I could reclassify the layer for display purposes.  The attached image shows the MODIS-based VCC layer over a basemap in ArcGIS.  You can see the effects of deforestation over a one year period.

[image]